# Can "significant_terms" aggregation be used with multi-fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't find any info in official documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significanttext-aggregation.html

The issue is that I try to aggregate significant terms on a "multi-field" (`name.shingles`) that has applied shingles filter/analyzer:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "significant_words": {
      "sampler": {
        "shard_size": 100
      }, 
      "aggs": {
        "keywords": {
          "significant_text": {
            "field": "name.shingles"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm getting empty buckets:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "significant_words" : {
      "doc_count" : 5,
      "keywords" : {
        "doc_count" : 5,
        "bg_count" : 153313,
        "buckets" : [ ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Multi-field definition:

```
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "shingles" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "shingle_analyzer",
              "fielddata" : true
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Significant Terms or Significant Text aggregation with multi-field as well.

But you need to understand how this aggregation work, You can check the documentation and  below is what mentioned in it.

> An aggregation that returns interesting or unusual occurrences of
> terms in a set.

> In all these cases the terms being selected are not simply the most
> popular terms in a set. They are the terms that have undergone a
> significant change in popularity measured between a foreground and
> background set. If the term "H5N1" only exists in 5 documents in a 10
> million document index and yet is found in 4 of the 100 documents that
> make up a user’s search results that is significant and probably very
> relevant to their search. 5/10,000,000 vs 4/100 is a big swing in
> frequency.

Also, It seems like you have very less number of document in index after looking your aggregation result `"doc_count" : 5`. You can index large document set and then you can try it out this aggregation.

If you want to apply aggregation on shingle field then you can used terms aggregation as well:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sw": {
     "terms": {
       "field": "name.shingles",
       "size": 10
     }
    }
  }
}
```